# mongo Query failed with error code 4567 and error message

Tags: mongodb

Do somebody know what this error message mean from my java app to mongoDB:

```
 com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 4567 and error message 'from collection (testdb.testcol) cannot be sharded' on server myserver:27017
```

Comment: From which command? Is `testdb.testcol` any kind of special collection? Did you enable sharding on database level?

Comment: It is sharded collection , this is in the app logs , not clear the exact command causing it ...